# Error in solve.default(res$hessian*n.used,A): 'a' must be a complex matrix

Tags: function, arima

I am using the arima function in R's forecast package and I get the following error:

Error in solve.default(res$hessian*n.used,A): 'a' must be a complex matrix

The time series that I am fitting has very large values numbers e.g. greater than 10 million. Can anyone please provide a solution that might alleviate this error? Would scaling the time series help?